# Multiple Inserts with PostgreSQL if an entry does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, sql-insert

I would like to insert data into multiple tables if an entry does not exist.

In my case I have a restaurant table, a location table, a `foodtype` table and some helper tables like `restaurant_location`, and `restaurant_foodtype`. Now I would like to insert a new restaurant entry complete with the location and the foodtype info if the entry does not exist.

So something like:

```
IF NOT (select 1 from restaurant where name='restaurantname') THEN
 INSERT INTO restaurant(x,y) VALUES (valuex,valuey);
 INSERT INTO restaurant_location(rest_id,..) VALUES (rest_id,..);
 INSERT INTO restaurant_foodtype(rest_id,..) VALUES (rest_id,..);
 ...
END IF
```

How can I do this with simple SQL?

Comment: There's no "simple" SQL query that inserts into multiple tables. But it's easily done in procedural code in plpgsql, which looks quite like the pseudo-code in the question. If you can't use that for some reason, more info on the context would be welcome.

Comment: 8.1 has been out of support for a long time. You should upgrade ***now***, really.

Comment: @DanielVérité: Well, since Postgres 9.1 it can be done with a "simple" SQL statement using data-modifying CTEs. I posted an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrote this at the top of my head but this should be the idea, if you must do it with simple sql.

```
insert into 
    restaurant(x, y)
values
    select valuex, valuey 
    from dual
    where
      not exists(
        select 1 from restaurant where name = 'restaurantname')
```

---

**EDIT:**
Again, I couldn't parse it but you probably could make use of the WITH clause:

```
with validation as(
  select 1 from restaurant where name = 'restaurantname'
)
insert into 
    restaurant(x, y)
values
    (
     select value1x, value1y 
     from dual
     where
       validation.v = 1),
    (
     select value2x, value2y 
     from dual
     where
       validation.v = 1)
```

Comment: This works great for exactly one insert statement. But I have multiple ones. just adding the WHERE NOT EXISTS to every single INSERT does not work, cause after the first insert, the entry should exist

Comment: If the restaurant doesn't exist for the first row, you'll insert a row.  *That* restaurant's id number is accessible through the [currval() function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-sequence.html). You don't need to check related inserts for the existence of an id number; foreign key constraints guarantee it can't possibly exist unless your database design is badly broken.

Answer (score 9):

In Postgres **9.1 or later** you can use [**data-modifying CTEs**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) to make this fast, safe, simple and elegant:

```
WITH x AS (
   INSERT INTO restaurant(name, x, y)
   SELECT 'restaurantname', valuex, valuey
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM restaurant WHERE name = 'restaurantname')
   RETURNING rest_id     -- returns auto-generated id (from sequence)
   )
, y AS (
   INSERT INTO restaurant_location(rest_id, ...)
   SELECT rest_id, ...
   FROM   x              -- only produces rows after a successful INSERT
   )

   --- more chained INSERTs here?

INSERT INTO restaurant_foodtype(rest_id, ...)
SELECT rest_id, ...
FROM   x;
```

The first `INSERT` is only executed if 'restaurantname' is not found. There is a super-tiny race-condition if multiple queries should try the same in the same instance. If you have a `UNIQUE` constraint on `restaurant.name` (like you should judging from your description), the worst that could happen is that among concurring queries only the first would succeed while the others return with a unique violation (doing nothing). Chances are, however, you will never see this, because it is very unlikely to happen.

The `RETURNING` clause returns the automatically generated `rest_id` - I assume `rest_id`is a serial column.

The following `INSERT` queries only generate rows if the first one succeeded.

Finish the series with be a plain `INSERT`.

With PostgreSQL 8.1 I would write a plpgsql function to achieve the same.
But, really, you'd better upgrade to a [current version](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

Comment: That was basically what I had in mind when asking for the version ;)

Comment: Tis is "fast, safe, simple and elegant"?  I'm just using postGreSQL for one project, and I have to wonder if this really the simplest way to do this very comment operation.

Comment: If you wrap this in a function that returns a composite data type, an empty row (instead of no rows) is returned if exists. Why's that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700215/shouldnt-this-postgresql-function-return-zero-rows