# Shouldn't this PostgreSQL function return zero rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, user-defined-functions, return-type, create-function

Given the schema

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    email varchar(254) NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX on users (lower(email));

CREATE FUNCTION all_users() RETURNS users AS $$
    SELECT * FROM users;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

, shouldn't `SELECT * FROM all_users()` (assuming the `users` table is empty) return no rows, not a row with all `null` values?

See the SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b5ba8/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your function is *broken* by design. It should be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION all_users() RETURNS SETOF users AS
'SELECT * FROM users' LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Or alternatively, the more flexible form `RETURNS TABLE (...)` [like @Clodoaldo posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22700373/939860). But it's generally wiser to use `RETURNS SETOF users` for a query with `SELECT * FROM users`.

Your original function always returns a single value (a composite type), it has been declared that way. It will break in a more spectacular fashion if you insert some rows.

Consider this [**SQL Fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4d90d/3).

For better understanding, your function call does the same as this plain SELECT query:

```
SELECT (SELECT u from users u).*;
```

Returns:

```
id     | email
-------+------
<NULL> | <NULL>
```

The *difference*: Plain SQL will raise an exception if the subquery returns more than one row, while a function will just return the first row and discard the rest.

[As always, details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html)

Comment: Thank you! I simplified my function for this question. The last line of my real function either inserts one row or no rows, like http://stackoverflow.com/a/12160777/242933. Seems I should still use `SETOF` for `INSERT RETURNING` because multiple rows can be returned if I insert multiple values (although I'm not) and "if the INSERT command contains a RETURNING clause, the result will be similar to that of a SELECT statement containing the columns and values defined in the RETURNING list, computed over the row(s) inserted by the command." http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-insert.html

Answer (score 2):

Your function returns [records](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-type-system.html#AEN52662). So it must return at least one record. If you want an empty result set do return a table:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION all_users()
RETURNS table (id bigint, email varchar(254)) AS $$
    SELECT id, email FROM users;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

Comment: The OP's function doesn't actually return "records", nor "at least one record". It returns a single composite type (or a "row type" if you will) - just as declared. Your link is exactly right.

Comment: Also saying that is must return at least one record is a bit misleading - it must return exactly one row. If there are none - a row filled with nulls is returned.